# Can I execute inherited static functions from a BaseClass from a ChildClass and get the childs properties?

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, extends, base-class

I have a few cases where I want to add static functions or values in a base class so that I can use them in all subclasses that inherits from it.

One such case is when i want to create generic tags for each class to use in data mapping as a key, like when i want to find fragments or pass data between activities.

For example:

```
open class BaseClass(){

  companionObject{
    val TAG: String = this.javaClass.simpleName
  }
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass()

class Main: Activity(){

  fun startActivity(){
    val intent = Intent(this, ChildClass::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(ChildClass.TAG, data)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
  }
}
```

Can this be done or am I forced to create an companion object for each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a solution with companions. But you could use a global reified inline function for the specific use case, you mentioned in your question:

```
open class BaseClass()
class ChildClass: BaseClass()

inline fun <reified T> tagOf() = T::class.java.simpleName

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(tagOf<BaseClass>())
    println(tagOf<ChildClass>())
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty slick.
I will definitely try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... I think, you can't do it. As mentioned in this article: https://proandroiddev.com/a-true-companion-exploring-kotlins-companion-objects-dbd864c0f7f5
companion object is really a public static final class in your BaseClass. So, I think, you can't do this.